# Swing Components MergeSort Error

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to create GUI that change its elements if some others were selected. After hitting button it should disable itself and turn on another one. But JButton can't disable itself sometimes. And it throws: **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!**

It has something to do with error: **6923200 : swing LayoutComparator breaks transitivity that may lead to IllegalArgumentException**

It is suggested to add to eclipse ini a line: java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
But it is not working. Do you know any workaround for problem mentioned above?

^EDIT: It seems to me that it's not possible to change state of button twice in actionPerformed() method.

^EDIT2: SSCCE - I hope :)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    enableButtons(0, 0, 0, 0); //0 disables, 1 enables one of four buttons
    someFunction();
    enableButtons(1, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

It crashes:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.enumerateAndSortCycle(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFocusTraversalCycle(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getComponentAfter(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy.getComponentAfter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.getNextFocusCandidate(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.transferFocus(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.disable(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.disable(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.enable(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setEnabled(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setEnabled(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.setEnabled(Unknown Source)
    at CWindow.enableButtons(CWindow.java:83)
    at CWindow$2.actionPerformed(CWindow.java:254)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I would make sure you are using the GUI thread to make these changes.  Are you using any additional threads to update GUI components?

Comment: Show us the code, and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Changes are made in actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) and the problem occurred when I tried to change state of button twice in single run. So I assume that GUI is refreshed after actionPerformed method or something like that, am I right?

Comment: http://sscce.org/ if possible.

Comment: Sorry dude, I'm not seeing an SSCCE here.

Comment: What does `someFunction` actually do?  How does the comparable actually work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange Swing Error when from calling RemoveAll() on subclass of JPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060645/strange-swing-error-when-from-calling-removeall-on-subclass-of-jpanel)

Comment: That's not an SSCCE.  It is an SSCCE if I can save it to a file, compile it, run it, and see the behaviour that you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, `someFunction()` should NOT be run on EDT directly in the `actionPerformed()` method. The correct pattern looks like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    enableButtons(0, 0, 0, 0); //0 disables, 1 enables one of four buttons
    Thread worker = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            someFunction();
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    enableButtons(1, 1, 0, 0);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    worker.start();
}
```

You might ask why you need doubly-nested anonymous classes. First, time-consuming tasks should never run on the EDT, because they then block the whole GUI. That's what the Thread worker for - we run the task in its own thread. But when the task is finished, we want to re-enable some of the buttons - but that task manipulates Swing components and must be run within the EDT. That's what the SwingUtilities.invokeLater() is for - it allows a Runnable to be processed by the EDT.

Try modifying the code by my example and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Yea, it works fine, thanks. Could you perhaps let me now if there is any guide to Java that explains that kind of tricks? Simple guides that shows how to build application usually omits useful stuff like this.

Comment: There's the [canonical guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)