# Odd intermittent Java stacktrace since upgrading to 1.7.0_45, then program hangs doing graphics

Tags: java, swing

Since going to 1.7.0_45 (and 51) my program sometimes hangs. All of it's windows work OK except for one, it's fairly complex and has around 60 JButtons, JTextFields, two JScrollbars, JLabels etc. But so do all my other windows and they work fine.

I've put debug lines to the console so I can see where the program is hanging and it seems to be during the repaint() fn. It's hanging at the line

```
Graphics g = getGraphics();
```

It has managed to draw some stuff to the screen so it's not the first call to repaint that's the issue. Looks like this: http://www.unixnerd.demon.co.uk/hungjava.jpg

I get this StackTrace. None of the lines of code are in my program. It only happens maybe one time in ten if I open and close the window. Never had the issue with Java 1.6.x. Happens on a few PCs (all Windows 7), not just mine.

Grateful for any ideas.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.LayoutComparator.compare(LayoutComparator.java:116)
    at javax.swing.LayoutComparator.compare(LayoutComparator.java:42)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:329)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:189)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.enumerateAndSortCycle(SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.java:136)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFocusTraversalCycle(SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.java:110)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.java:435)
    at javax.swing.LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy.java:166)
    at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getDefaultComponent(SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.java:515)
    at java.awt.FocusTraversalPolicy.getInitialComponent(FocusTraversalPolicy.java:169)
    at java.awt.Window.getMostRecentFocusOwner(Window.java:2317)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:681)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.SequencedEvent.dispatch(SequencedEvent.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Why are you calling getGraphics() on a component? Chances are that has always been incorrect but just now threw an exception now that you're running on a different JRE.

Comment: @KevinWorkman The exception doesn't have to do with that call.

Comment: I would still bet that the problem has to do with improper painting, probably from different threads. But there's no way to tell without a compilable example.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I bet this is a threading issue. OP is executing some GUI code without `invokeLater`.

Comment: OP, check out this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5060952/1103872. It is closely related.

Comment: Yes, it was an invokeLater issue - that fixed it. I first used Java under 1.0 and I've not kept up to date with some of these new things! :-) Still get a small number of uncaught exceptions from the EDT but I'm working on that.... Thanks for your help.